# How can use a new font in iphone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to used the particular fonts for my application. But I don't how can use that font that are in the iPhone SDK library.
Any idea how can I do this ?

By the way I want to use hindi and punjabi fonts in it.

Answer (score 3):

The [FontLabel](http://github.com/zynga/FontLabel) open source project provides a means of drawing your own .ttf fonts on the iPhone.

Comment: I don't think the source can be downloaded from github because the terminal say "-bash: git://github.com/zynga/FontLabel.git: No such file or directory" may the folder does not exists or is corrupted

Comment: @Madhup you have to install git (http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/), and then run `git clone git://github.com/zynga/FontLabel.git`

Comment: @Madhup: Also, there is a "Download source" button in the upper-right of the page that lets you download a Zip archive of the project.

Comment: sorry I was doin a silly mistake in running the command. I had the installer installed but I didn't typed "git clone"

Answer (score 2):

There is *currently* no *official* way to do this; but given the presentations of iWork on the iPad, it's possible that the 3.2 SDK adds this.

**Edit:** Assuming Jasarien is right about this; you'd probably be better off developing for iPhone OS 3.2; as you'll need an iPhone Dev Central membership to publish your applications at any rate; you might as well get started right away.

Comment: @Jasarien true but they will be merging the 3.2 (iPad only) with iPhone branches eventually (my guess at 4.0 in June/July). There are some iPad specific things that make no sense on an iPhone but this is one that it seems likely that the iPhone will get it.

Comment: That's pure speculation that isn't safe to rely on and isn't relevant to this point in time, or the question at hand.